# Spring: Could not resolve placeholder 'properties.string' in value '${properties.string}'

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, spring-tool-suite

I'm getting an error when trying to run a Spring application where I am trying to inject dependencies from an application.properties file. Thus, Spring cannot create the bean.

This is the bean that cannot be created without the dependencies:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {
    
    private String url;
    private String id;
    private String secret;
    private String scope;
    private String tenantId;
    private String siteId;
    private String listId;

    @Autowired
    public ClientConfig(
            @Value("${client.url}") String url, 
            @Value("${client.id}")String id, 
            @Value("${client.secret}") String secret, 
            @Value("${client.scope}") String scope, 
            @Value("${client.tenantId}") String tenantId,
            @Value("${client.siteId}") String siteId,
            @Value("${client.listId}") String listId) {

        this.url = url;
        this.id = id;
        this.secret = secret;
        this.scope = scope;
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
        this.siteId = siteId;
        this.listId = listId;
    }


        public ClientConfig() {
        
        }
    
        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getSecret() {
            return secret;
        }

        public String getScope() {
            return scope;
        }

        public String getTenantId() {
            return tenantId;
        }


        public String getSiteId() {
            return siteId;
        }

        public String getListId() {
            return listId;
        }

}
```

These are the values in the application.properties file located in src/main/resources:

```
client:
  url: https://google.com
  id: ${CLIENT_ID}
  secret: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
  scope: https://scope.url.com
  tenantId: 000-000-000
  siteId: "google.com/site/mysite"
  listId: "my-list"
```

The id and secret come from the environment.

I have tried a few different things. I have tried to use the `@PropertySource` annotation with the `classpath:application.properties`, but I get an error that the file doesn't exist. I tried moving those @Value tags outside the constructor. I have also tried to hard-code the values within the ClientConfig class. When I did that, I got an error that looked like this:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.graph.GraphConfig required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

I'm new to Spring, but based on the training I have done, it seems like if the dependencies are hard-coded right within the class the application context would definitely be able to inject them. I know hard-coding them is not the answer so I'm not even worried about the second error.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is named `application.properties` but its content you showed is in `.yml`-format.

In `.properties`-format your configuration would look like this:

```
client.url=https://google.com
client.id=${CLIENT_ID}
client.secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}
client.scope=https://scope.url.com
client.tenantId=000-000-000
client.siteId=google.com/site/mysite
client.listId=my-list
```

Alternatively you could use an `application.yml` file instead as described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-yaml-vs-properties

Comment: Made the above changes. Still getting errors about not being able to resolve the placeholder:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'graph.tokenUrl' in value "${graph.tokenUrl}"
`

Comment: @shannon Where in your code is the placeholder `graph.tokenUrl`? I only see `{client.url}`